# Template dispatch in XSLT based on attribute value

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'd like to know if it's possible to dispatch to `<xsl:template>` in XSLT (2.0) based on attribute value. Let's assume the following example XML:

```
<root>
    <field code="a">Content A</field>
    <field code="b">Content B</field>
</root>
```

I want to write an XPath selector for the `<xsl:template>` `match` attribute that will dispatch processing to templates defined for each value of a given attribute. A naïve approach could compare attribute value in every template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="field"/>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field[@code = 'a']">
        Code A processing...
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field[@code = 'b']">
        Code B processing...
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Similarly, one could use `<xsl:choose>` and `<xsl:when>` for every possible code value, in which `<xsl:call-template/>` could be used, calling a dedicated named template.

Is there a better solution for doing template dispatch based on attribute value?

Comment: Avoid `<xsl:choose>` in favor of template matching, if you can (sometimes you can't, like when testing against variable or parameter values).

Comment: Exactly. My preferred way is definitely by using template matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is valid in both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, and it's also good practice. What's the problem?

Comment: I thought there might be a way how to match the attribute value directly and thus avoid a bit of repetition with `field[@code = 'dispatch value']`.

Comment: @jindrichm, you can match on e.g. `field/@code[. = 'b']`. But usually only makes sense if you want to transform that attribute into a different one or at least simply output its value. If the transformation or output for the `field` differs based on the attribute then it is usually easier to treat the difference in a template matching the element.